# find a range of values in std::list

Tags: c++, stl

Is there an algorithm to find a range of values ​​in the std::list, could do such action:

```
list<char> text;
text.push_back('a');
text.push_back('b');
text.push_back('c');
text.push_back('d');
text.push_back('e');
text.push_back('f');

list<char> values;
values.push_back('c');
values.push_back('d');
values.push_back('e');

list<char>::iterator it = find(text.begin(), text.end(), values);
```

Comment: what do you mean by `find a range of values` should they be consecutive in the list or not?

Comment: Yes, consecutive in the list

Comment: I m asking for **str.find("what")** but using **list<char>** instead of **string**

Comment: Just for reference, `list<char>` seems like an odd way to represent text.

Comment: It is more effective to insert characters in the middle of the string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search)

```
list<char>::iterator it = search(text.begin(), text.end(),
                                 values.begin(), values.end());
```